# how do i pass a result from one search into IN clause of another search in splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

i run a query and get list of custId in form of table. how do i pass this result into another search query inside IN clause.

eg:

search 1: index=* "successful login for"|table custID
 this gives me table with column custID.

Then i have to run

index=* "mail sent by"|where custID IN (search 1) |table CustID,_time

Comment: Basically what i want is , i have a serach query that give me custId and time when he signed up. another search query give me time for when a user first used a service say, sent a mail. i want to know after how many days of signing up each customer first used that service

Answer (score 5):

Use a subsearch.  You'll have to experiment with `format` options to get the output to be compatible with `IN`.

```
index=* "mail sent by"|where custID IN ([search index=* "successful login for"|fields custID | format]) |table CustID,_time
```

If you can't get the `format` output right, you may have to use the old method without `IN`.

```
index=* "mail sent by"|where [search index=* "successful login for"|fields custID | format] |table CustID,_time
```

BTW, `index=*` is not a good practice for Production.  Use the real index name for better performance.

Comment: it did not work. basically what i want is , i have a serach query that give me custId and time when he signed up. another search query give me time for when a user first used a service say, sent a mail. i want to know after how many days of signing up each customer first used that service.

Answer (score 4):

```
index=myindex <mainSearchConditions>
custID IN (
   [search index=myindex <subsearchConditions> | table custID | dedup custID 
   | stats values(eval("\"".custID."\"")) as search delim="," | nomv search]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By its nature, Splunk search can return multiple items. Generally, this takes the form of a list of events or a table. [Subsearch](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/Useasubsearch) is no different -- it may returns multiple results, of course.

Subsearch output is converted to a query term that is used directly to constrain your search (via [`format`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Format)):

> This command is used implicitly by subsearches. This command takes the results of a subsearch, formats the results into a single result and places that result into a new field called search.

The above quote from the documentation is a cryptic way of saying that ***the subsearch results are converted into a query expression to match any of the subsearch outputs***.

As such, the results of subsearch are effectively the same as applying the [IN operator](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/Search/Predicates#IN_operator) -- each subsearch result will be a matched value. So you don't need to use `IN` to achieve the intended results.

---

### Example: The OP's use-case

`index=* "mail sent by"|where custID IN (search 1) |table CustID,_time`

would be written as:

`index=* "mail sent by" [search {search 1}] |table CustID,_time`

Since `(search 1)` produces a table with column `custID`, the subsearch needs no additional massaging to achieve the specified result. The subsearch will be replaced with something like:

`( (custID="result1") OR (custID="result") OR ...)`

---

### Example: Selecting items matching the max value

`[search index=main |stats max(batch) as batch]`

The subsearch returns a table with a single column and a single item. For the outer query to work as intended, *it is important to rename the column (using `as`) from 'max(batch)' to 'batch'* so that it will match against the 'batch' field in the original data.

The resulting query expression will look like:

`( batch="{max(batch)}" )`

Comment: Although the 'max' example uses only a single value and wouldn't require `IN`, it's illustrative of how subsearch works in the simplest case. You can build up from there.